# Setting DHCP and DNS servers

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dhcp, ping, local-area-network

This is the topology I'm working with:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVFYh.png)

I have configured the routers like this:

`Router_1_Mikrotik`

```
ip address
add address=192.168.10.10/25 interface=ether1
add address=192.168.10.130/26 interface=ether2
add address=192.168.10.161/30 interface=ether4
ip route
add dst-address=192.168.10.224/27 gateway=192.168.10.162
------------------------------------------------------------
[admin@MikroTik] /ip dhcp-server> setup
Select interface to run DHCP server on

dhcp server interface: ether1
Select network for DHCP addresses

dhcp address space: 192.168.10.0/25
Select gateway for given network

gateway for dhcp network: 192.168.10.10
Select pool of ip addresses given out by DHCP server

addresses to give out: 192.168.10.1-192.168.10.9,192.168.10.11-192.168.10.126
Select DNS servers

dns servers: 192.168.10.227
Select lease time

lease time: 99999m
------------------------------------------------------------
[admin@MikroTik] /ip dhcp-server> setup
Select interface to run DHCP server on

dhcp server interface: ether2
Select network for DHCP addresses

dhcp address space: 192.168.10.128/26
Select gateway for given network

gateway for dhcp network: 192.168.10.130
Select pool of ip addresses given out by DHCP server

addresses to give out: 192.168.10.129,192.168.10.131-192.168.10.190
Select DNS servers

dns servers: 192.168.10.227
Select lease time

lease time: 99999m
```

`Router_2_Cisco`

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
ip address 192.168.10.162 255.255.255.252
no shutdown

interface Ethernet1/0
ip address 192.168.10.230 255.255.255.224
no shutdown

ip route 192.168.10.128 255.255.255.192 192.168.10.161
ip route 192.168.10.0   255.255.255.128 192.168.10.161
```

And the 3 servers:

```
DHCP
ip address
add address=192.168.10.225/27 interface=ether1
ip route
add gateway=192.168.10.230

WEB
ip address
add address=192.168.10.226/27 interface=ether1
ip route
add gateway=192.168.10.230
ip dns static 
add name=www.example.com address=10.1.1.1

DNS
ip address
add address=192.168.10.227/27 interface=ether1
ip route
add gateway=192.168.10.230
```

Question 1:

I'm using `DHCP` on `Router_1_Mikrotik` to automatically give IP addresses to `VPC_LAN_A` and `VPC_LAN_B`. That is working correctly, since the LANS have IP address and I can ping from LAN_A and LAN_B to the servers. Is it correctly configured though?

Question 2:

I want to be able to access www.company.com from the LANS.
I've configured the `Mikrotik_CHR_Web` like this shown above but I can't ping from the server to that domain?

Comment: Hi. This question is detailed and specific but you may want to embed the image instead of just linking to it. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Hi. I know but I think I don't have 10 reputation on this account

Comment: Is this a real network scenario or a training scenario? Those are some pretty unusual network addresses.

Comment: It's work for college. I have to use the same subnet (192.168.10.x) and divide it through the lans